# In Android how long textview with multiple lines fit into the screen?

Tags: android

I have a long texts with multiple lines..

So,I have tried :--

**activity_into.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bck"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="overview" 
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/intro" 
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Here "**@string/intro**" is a long text with multiple lines.
With above code I texts:--[Like this](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/device-2011-08-16-152509nex.png),,
this texts are not fit into the screen..

I want little space between the left and right side with a good text style..How can i achieve that?????

Comment: for spacing use margin_left and margin_right. if you want to change the font.. add it in styles and use android:textstyle property

Comment: add margin_left and margin_right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo need to apply padding to give space on sides:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bck"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="overview" 
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/intro" 
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can give `android:padding="10dip"` if you need to give same padding in all directions.

Comment: Thanks bro..Its fantastic...But I cant accept ur answer..Because i have only 8 points..

Comment: @SomChatterjee upvoting requires repo. you can accept :) click on right tick on left.

Comment: Sorry Its saying you need 15 reputation to voting up

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bck"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="overview" 
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/intro" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Take ScrollView as parent of second TextView so when text out screen it apply scroll and given your left and right padding to ScrollView here i also give weight to ScrollView so it will take rest height after First Textview content.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bck"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="overview"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/intro"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```